# .NET 8 Azure function throws error when using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-8.0

I am writing an Azure function and it needs to use .NET 8. I am trying to do simple task of serializing an object to JSON. However, I am getting the following error. If I change the framework to .NET 6, it works perfectly, but my requirements state I need to use .NET 8

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ExportToJson. AzureFunctions: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here is my function:

```
using Core.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureFunctions
{
    public class ConvertToJson
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ConvertToJson> _logger;

        public ConvertToJson(ILogger<ConvertToJson> logger) 
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        [FunctionName("ConvertToJson")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *"
            #if DEBUG
                , RunOnStartup = true
            #endif
            )]TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            try
            {
                var output = new OutputObject();
                string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(output);
                _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ConvertToJson)} finished at: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is thrown when I add the line

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(output);
```

The project builds without errors and if I remove that line it runs fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue I created a new project that targeted .net8 Azure functions instead of trying to update an existing project that originally targeted .net6 and was changed to .net8 afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update the Nuget package or `System.Text.Json`.The older version exists in error due to the intermediate obj files not being recompiled. Do a clean build and force older files to recompile.

And also try to add this property into your project file,

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I also saw this suggestion while searching stackoverflow but it did not help. The only way I could get around the error was to create a brand new project targeting .net8 instead of changing the existing from .net6 to .net8